# Resample or Groupby from the bottom up

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe of AAPL prices.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
prices = yf.download('aapl', interval='1d', period='2y')
```

What I am looking to achieve is a 7d grouping of the data **that will end up at the same timestamp in the last row as the original data**.

The original *prices* dataframe ends on 2023-01-10, whereas if I do

```
prices.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='7d')).mean()
# or
prices.resample('7d').mean()
```

the ending timestamp is 2023-01-09. How can I groupby 7d so it always ends in the same timestamp as the original?

**Update**

It seems there is the **convention** param in resample(), didn't know that. With it you can specify whether it will use the start or end in the timestamps to do the resampling. Eager to know the solution for the groupby too though!

Comment: `pd.Grouper` also has the `convention` parameter :)

Comment: I'm not sure `convention='end'` gives you the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `origin='end'` as parameter of `resample`:

```
>>> prices.resample('7d', origin='end').mean()

                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close       Volume
Date                                                                               
2021-01-12  128.845001  129.930000  127.680000  128.889999  127.361107   96167800.0
2021-01-19  129.029999  130.345001  127.797501  128.692501  127.165956   95303600.0
2021-01-26  137.082004  140.280002  135.013998  138.810001  137.163440  118986420.0
2021-02-02  137.651999  138.944003  134.572000  136.048001  134.434216  130106780.0
2021-02-09  136.412000  137.086002  134.966000  136.201999  134.707361   79565840.0
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...          ...
2022-12-13  143.817999  145.386002  141.460001  143.142001  143.142001   74459060.0
2022-12-20  137.930002  138.912000  134.426001  135.778000  135.778000   99681080.0
2022-12-27  132.407501  133.799999  130.352501  132.392498  132.392498   74150700.0
2023-01-03  129.087500  130.589996  126.300001  127.662498  127.662498   87555050.0
2023-01-10  128.151999  130.277998  126.548000  128.375996  128.375996   78471420.0

[105 rows x 6 columns]
```